# Develop web apps without IIS installed on localhost?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7

I hope I am posting this on the right section...

I've been trying to find **"best practice"** documents or **"VS 2010 web development requirements"** regarding this but no luck.
Basically, I believe that I need IIS on my localhost for general debugging purposes of my web app. 
Perhaps, there is a way to connect to a remote IIS  but I am sure my development time will increase by a lot. 
It is the same case when you only use the "VS Development Server". I think, it is not best practice to recompile and run my web application on debug mode  (F5) in order to see what I am coding.
If I don't have my website running on my localhost , I can't "Attach to process" either.

Please keep on mind this scenario happen when you are building a web app from scratch. Not something that its already deployed and live.

Any thoughts or comments will  be very much appreciated.
Thanks!

PD: Windows 7 + VS2010 Profesional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58wxa9w5.aspx

if it helps, I always run using the internal development server on 2008 with no problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

I develop web apps using the internal server of Visual Studio with no problem. This seems like the easiest way to do it. Are you having some problem with this? What is your concern?

You can run a local IIS server. It's included with the "professional" versions of Windows, so all you have to do is turn it on. Once you get it up and running, you can add new apps within a generic "web site" pretty easily. But I've only done this a few times and then for pretty specialized reasons. Mostly I run run the VS interal server.